# PayPal Error While Using Debit or Credit Card

Tags: paypal

Below error I got

"You cannot use an e-mail address or card number that belongs to an existing PayPal account. If you have a PayPal account, please log in. If you don't, please change the e-mail address or card number and try again."

I have created a application, while i am checking that app, i goat above error, i changed card numbers and email id's but paypal is still showing that error.

and finally my cart is _xclick

If you want any other info write a comment.

Plz do the need full

Comment: Show code of what you're sending to PayPal (hide the email address if you need to)

Answer (score 2):

The first time you pay through PayPal, PayPal automatically creates an account in their system against your c/card number and email address.

Later, if you ever try to use PayPal again and enter either the same c/card nbr or email address, PayPal recognises that you have an 'account' with them and requires you to login. ie you cannot check-out as a 'guest' with the same email address or c/card.

PayPal forces you to login to your account. Since you didn't consciously create an account in the first place, many people find this experience confusing and frustrating.

Unless you want to use a different c/card and email address, you'll need to login to your 'account' Since you inevitably won't know your PayPal password, you'll need to follow the process to login, then click the link to recover your password, which will be sent to your email address. You can then use it to login and complete your payment by c/card through PayPal.

Many of your customers will have unfortunately given up by this point.